# --files in SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS not working in zeppelin

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a python package with many modules built into an .egg file and  I want to use this inside zeppelin notebook. Acc to the zeppelin documentation, to pass this package to zeppelin spark interpreter, you can export it through --files option in SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS in conf/zeppelin-env.sh.

When I add the .egg through the --files option in SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS , zeppelin notebook is not throwing error, but I am not able to import the module inside the zeppelin notebook.

What's the correct way to pass an .egg file zeppelin spark intrepreter?

Spark version is 1.6.2 and zeppelin version is 0.6.0

The zepplein-env.sh file contains the follwing:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/me/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--jars /home/me/spark-csv-1.5.0-s_2.10.jar,/home/me/commons-csv-1.4.jar --files /home/me/models/Churn-zeppelin/package/build/dist/fly_libs-1.1-py2.7.egg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to adjust the PYTHONPATH on the executor nodes:

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="... --conf 'spark.executorEnv.PYTHONPATH=fly_libs-1.1-py2.7.egg:pyspark.zip:py4j-0.10.3-src.zip' ..."
```

It does not seem to be possible to append to an existing python path, therefore make sure you list all the required dependencies.